# How to reset the state before render is called in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am displaying a Popup when I click on a copy icon. When I click the copy icon, I set the state "showPopup" to true. My render function now sees that it's true, and displays the popup. The popup automatically closes if I click outside anywhere else.

So far so good.

The problem is I have a dropdown on the same screen with a list of selections. When I click any selection from the dropdown, it also changes another variable in the state which causes a re-render.

However, the previous state of "showPopup" is true and not false. So no matter where I click on the same screen now, I am always showing the popup. I only want it to appear when I specifically click the copy button.

Any idea how I can fix this, I tried componentDidUpdate like so:

```
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (prevState.showPopup === true) {
      this.setState({showPopup: false});
    }};
```

But this causes an issue when the second time I try to click the copy icon again. This time the popup will only appear every 2 times I click the copy icon...

any idea how I can make sure that the initial state for showPopup is always reset to false?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code so that we can provide you with more accurate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My answer without being able to see any of your code would be to set the showPopup to false when the dropdown is changed

```
<select onChange={() => this.setState({showPopup: false})}>
<option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like above, this is my answer without being able to see your code. You need to set showPopup to false in your onCLose action within the popup. Here is a lazy example of what I am talking about.

```
<Popover onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)} />
```

This event will be triggered any time the popover is closed (which includes clicking away), and thus your state will be set to false.

EDIT:
I was using React state hooks and I just realized you were using a class component so it would actually look like:

```
<Popover onClose={() => this.setState({showPopup: false})} />
```

However, for anyone using a functional component and state hooks, use the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared your code so I am providing my solution without seeing your code.

You should update the "showPopup" state separately, in a method called onClick action of copy component instead of updating it in componentDidUpdate.